# how to lock device but prevent the screen to be turned off in android?

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

I'm using `DevicePolicyManager` to lock the device while needed. what I want is to bring up the lock screen but using `DevicePolicyManager` and calling it's method `lockNow()` will lock the device and turn the screen off. how to prevent turning off the screen?

**UPDATE:** I have tried this:

```
public class LockMeNowActivity extends Activity {
protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
private DevicePolicyManager mgr = null;
private ComponentName cn = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(com.commonsware.android.lockme.R.layout.main);
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    cn = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
    mgr = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
}

public void lockMeNow(View v) {
    if (mgr.isAdminActive(cn)) {

        mgr.lockNow();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, cn);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                "For experimentation purposes only");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public void pullWakeLock() {
    mWakeLock.acquire();
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    pullWakeLock();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    releaseWakeLock();
}

public void releaseWakeLock() {
    mWakeLock.release();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Along with your lockNow(), add **PowerManager.WakeLock**:

Import

```
import android.os.PowerManager;
```

Global Variable

```
protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
```

Public Methods

```
    public void pullWakeLock() {
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        this.mWakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public void releaseWakeLock() {
        this.mWakeLock.release();
    }
```

Use the follwing permission in manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't tested, but try both.

Comment: Okay try this. Call lockNow() in your activity normally... then on your `onPause()` call the `pullWakeLock()` method and in your `onResume()` call `releaseWakeLock()` method. Try that

Comment: I updated the post with what i have tried based on your last suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way for this problem. as I want to lock the device when `onStop()` happens I did:

```
    public void onStop() {
    mgr.lockNow();
    super.onStop();
    WakeLock screenLock = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE))
            .newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                    | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
    screenLock.acquire();
}
```

and it worked well. turning on the screen after locking it...

Comment: I am doing the same in my code and it works EXCEPT for when I:
1. Flash the device
2. Set screen lock
3. Use this code
Any advice?